# Execute sh script and send informations

Tags: shell, php

I want to execute a **.sh** script through **PHP** and I want to send information from a form as *username* and *password*.

The shell script gets executed with the `./name.sh` and then it asks for an input from the user as the following:

```
Enter your Username: xxxxxxxxx //<-- The Input you normally type in the terminal
```

And then one PHP `POST` variable should get passed there.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### IMPORTANT DISCLAIMER

Just realized after writing the answer: Asking for user input and including it on shell scripts without pre-processing is really dangerous, as a malicious user could inject code. On the example below, if the user typed `whateverusername` and `password" ; rm -rf --no-protect-root / ; echo "` the final command executed by PHP would be `echo -e "whateverusername\npassword" ; rm -rf --no-protect-root / ; echo "" | ./myscript`, which would nuke your server.

***Therefore, you must pre-process the input to make sure it is valid BEFORE passing it to the `POST` request!***

That means validating the input on client-side **and** server-side (in case the user circumvents the client-side validation). Something like:

*Client POST request -> Client-side validation (i.e. JS) -> Server-side pre-processing script -> Final POST to your PHP page with the sanitized strings*

---

Say your script is expecting two variables, $username and $password, that were supposed to be read by `read`. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Type username: "
read username
echo "Type password: "
read password
```

`read` will expect an string from *stdin* and will stop reading when it reaches a newline. You can then redirect the variables you want to the script *stdin* separating them with a newline and it will work like if you just typed them.

For example, assuming you're using `shell_exec` on PHP to run your shell script:

```
<?php
    $shelloutput = shell_exec('echo -e "' . $_POST["username"] . '\n' . $_POST["password"] . '" | ./myscript');
?>
```

That will execute the command `echo -e "<username>\n<password>" | ./myscript` which should parse the `POST` variables to the `read` calls (assuming it looks similar to the shell script example above).

---

Another alternative is to use Here-Documents:

```
<?php
    $shelloutput = shell_exec('./myscript << _EOF_'."\n".$_POST["username"]."\n".$_POST["password"]."\n".'_EOF_');
?>
```

Comment: Does it mather if the input (username for example) is expected after lets say 5 seconds (because the script is busy or so long)?

Comment: and a other question: can this be done for a coffee script also?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the script is busy, because *stdin* will be available for it once it's not busy anymore. About the *coffeescript*, I believe it would work too, though I never used it.. By the way, read the disclaimer I just added to the answer! There's some serious issues you've to consider before implementing that.

Comment: jeah I know I read it :) thanks :) so is there an other way beside php to do so? or is it the only way to pass values from a form to a coffeescript/shell script?

Comment: As far as I know you can use any CGI script to do that. The language must support accessing environment variables and working with *stdin* / *stdout*. If you configure the web server properly, it can be written in Perl, Python, Ruby, C, whatever you choose. You will probably still have to deal with the input pre-processing in whatever language you choose. Some will make it easier to pre-process it though, with more ellaborate string manipulation functions.